# ANTLR: Skipping NewLine depending on context without using actions

Tags: parsing, antlr

I try to make an ANTLR grammar for a data, which contains a part, where I can skip `NewLine`, and a part, where it may be important. More specifically, I'm interested in skipping `NewLine` inside parentheses and want to realize that using lexer modes. But there is the problem: in `DEFAULT_MODE` there are a lot of lexer rules, and tokens, that are described in these rules, can appear inside 
parentheses too. How can I solve the problem?

Maybe the current state of my code will help to understand the question

```
// ...

LPAREN : '(' -> pushMode(InsideParen) ;

// ...

mode InsideParen ;
InsideParenNewLine : ('\r'? '\n') -> skip ;

// here I want somehow recognize all tokens from DEFAULT_MODE without rewriting all rules

RPAREN: ')' -> popMode ;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is ANTLR3?  Or do you want to do these actions in ANTLR4?

Comment: @JLH It is ANTLR3

Comment: I'm an ANTLR4 guy.  However, the behavior you're talking about is similar to the way Python treats whitespace.  Suggest you look for an ANTL3 Python grammar and take some hints from that.  There has to be one out there.  Good luck!

Comment: @JLH thanks for the response! I'll look right now.

Comment: @JLH I have to ask. How would this problem be solved in ANTLR4?

Comment: @JLH sorry, I need to read carefully...

Comment: Too lengthy for a comments, posted it as an answer instead, hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I saw this question, I thought that your problem resembled that for Python newline handling.  But then I noticed you were using pushMode, which is not an ANTLR4 construct...

If you are willing up upgrade to ANTLR4 however, you can take advantage of stuff like:

```
LINENDING:             (('\r'? '\n')+ {self._lineContinuation=False}
    |      '\\'  [ \t]* ('\r'? '\n')  {self._lineContinuation=True})
{
if self._openBRCount == 0 and not self._lineContinuation:
    if not self._suppressNewlines:
        self.emitNewline()
        self._suppressNewlines = True
    la = self._input.LA(1)
    if la not in [ord(' '), ord('\t'), ord('#')]:
        self._suppressNewlines = False
        self.emitFullDedent()
} -> channel(HIDDEN)
   ;

OPEN_PAREN:     '(' {self._openBRCount  += 1};
CLOSE_PAREN:    ')' {self._openBRCount  -= 1};
OPEN_BRACE:     '{' {self._openBRCount  += 1};
CLOSE_BRACE:    '}' {self._openBRCount  -= 1};
OPEN_BRACKET:   '[' {self._openBRCount  += 1};
CLOSE_BRACKET:  ']' {self._openBRCount  -= 1};

UNKNOWN: . -> skip;
```

This will make your grammar act like Python with regard to whitespace, and maybe some tweaks where you act on parenthese instead of line continuation characters.  See [this python grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python2/Python2.g4).